# I want to add an value to an array, trying using splice, but it want work?

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice, array-splice

Im having problem with getting splice to work for my /home.

Im clearly doing something wrong but I cant figure out what, please help?

```js
const logArray = [
  "|timestamp              |url           |userid|",
  "|2019-03-01 09:00:00UTC |/contact.html |12345 |",
  "|2019-03-01 09:00:00UTC |/contact.html |12346 |",
  "|2019-03-01 10:00:00UTC |/contact.html |12345 |",
  "|2019-03-01 10:30:00UTC |/home.html    |12347 |",
  "|2019-03-01 11:00:00UTC |/contact.html |12347 |",
  "|2019-03-02 11:00:00UTC |/contact.html |12348 |",
  "|2019-03-02 12:00:00UTC |/home.html    |12348 |",
  "|2019-03-03 13:00:00UTC |/home.html    |12349 |",
  ""
];

let result = [];

const urls = () => {
  const url = logArray.map((Objects, index, arr) => {
    return Objects.slice(25, 38);
  });
  console.log("url:", url);
  if (url) {
    const contact = url.find((a) => a.includes("contact"));
    result.push(contact);
    console.log(contact);
    //console.log(contact)
  }
  if (url) {
    const home = url.find((a) => a.includes("home"));
    result.splice(3, 0, home);
    console.log(home);
  }
};
urls();
console.log(result);
```

and I have counted the unique user ids on each url and no. of visits on each url.

So I get this array back, no splice at all?!:

```
console.log("result:", result); //output ["/contact.html", "/home.html   ", 5, 4, 1, 1]
```

this is what I would like it to look like:

```
// dream scenario: ["/contact.html", 5, 4, "/home.html", 1, 1]
```

When I take the splice function out of the code and try it in codepen it works fine....but not in the fully code

Comment: Your code does not produce that output. I moved your code into a snippet so it can be run. There are no numbers stored in `result`. Please make sure we can reproduce the problem you raise.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, this isn't the best variant to parse log data but if you want. That's solution

```js
const logArray = [
  "|timestamp              |url           |userid|",
  "|2019-03-01 09:00:00UTC |/contact.html |12345 |",
  "|2019-03-01 09:00:00UTC |/contact.html |12346 |",
  "|2019-03-01 10:00:00UTC |/contact.html |12345 |",
  "|2019-03-01 10:30:00UTC |/home.html    |12347 |",
  "|2019-03-01 11:00:00UTC |/contact.html |12347 |",
  "|2019-03-02 11:00:00UTC |/contact.html |12348 |",
  "|2019-03-02 12:00:00UTC |/home.html    |12348 |",
  "|2019-03-03 13:00:00UTC |/home.html    |12349 |",
  ""
];

function getDataFromLogs(logs) {
  const formattedLogs = logs.slice(1, logs.length - 1)
  const urls = {}

    formattedLogs.map(log => {
    const route = log.slice(25, 38);
    const userID = log.slice(40, 46);
  
    if (urls[route] === undefined) {
            urls[route] = []
    }
    urls[route].push(userID)
  })
  
  const results = [];
  
  Object.keys(urls).map(key => {
    const data = urls[key];
    results.push(key.trim(), data.length, [...new Set(data)].length);
  })
  
  return results;
}
// ["/contact.html", 5, 4, "/home.html", 3, 3]
console.log(getDataFromLogs(logArray))
```

Answer (score 0):

These are the following steps in the solution -

1. Skip header row by [`Array.prototype.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)
2. Split by delimiter `|`
3. Count the url key
4. Accumulate the object based on the url key
5. Now post accumulating, count the number of accumulated entries stored in `items.length` and for distinct userId(s) use a set to count it.
6. Flatten the structure using [`Array.prototype.flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to meet your desired result

```js
const logArray = [
  "|timestamp              |url           |userid|",
  "|2019-03-01 09:00:00UTC |/contact.html |12345 |",
  "|2019-03-01 09:00:00UTC |/contact.html |12346 |",
  "|2019-03-01 10:00:00UTC |/contact.html |12345 |",
  "|2019-03-01 10:30:00UTC |/home.html    |12347 |",
  "|2019-03-01 11:00:00UTC |/contact.html |12347 |",
  "|2019-03-02 11:00:00UTC |/contact.html |12348 |",
  "|2019-03-02 12:00:00UTC |/home.html    |12348 |",
  "|2019-03-03 13:00:00UTC |/home.html    |12349 |",
  ""
];

const result = Object.entries(logArray
.slice(1)
.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    if (curr) {
        let [,, url, userId] = curr.trim().split('|');
        url = url.trim();
        userId = userId.trim();
        
        acc[url] = (acc[url] || []).concat({
                url,
                userId
        });
    }
    
    return acc;
}, Object.create(null)))
.reduce((r, c) => {
    const [key, items] = c;
    const distinctItemCount = new Set(items.map(x => x.userId)).size;
    r.push([key, items.length, distinctItemCount]);
    return r;
}, [])
.flat();

console.log(result);
```